# Laravel with Mailgun setup

Tags: laravel, mailgun, laravel-mail

I'm having troubles setting up Mailgun with Laravel.  I keep getting the following message:

```
ClientException in RequestException.php line 111:
Client error: `POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3//messages.mime` resulted in a `     
404 NOT FOUND` response:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested (truncated...)
```

Not sure what to do.  Here is the basic setup I followed:

The .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME='sandbox8e8c3965d4d14cac9d4f346c3d******'
MAIL_PASSWORD='e662ad1bbef5efd44cb96d32d6******'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

The config/mail.php file

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => [
    'address' => 'west**********@gmail.com',
    'name' => 'My Name is here',
],
 'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
 'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
 'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
 'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

My Route file contains the following

```
Route::post('sendMail', function(\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer $mailer, \Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {

$title = $request->title;
$content = $request->content;

$mailer->to('westtexascentral@gmail.com')->send(new \App\Mail\MyMailer($title, $content));

return 'Mail sent.';
});
```

And my Mailer Class contains the following:

```
public $title;
public $content;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($title, $content)
{
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->content = $content;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('kaley36_aw@yahoo.com')->view('emails.mail');
}
```

I'm hoping that I just over looked something simple, which is the hardest things to solve sometimes, but any help would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Mailgun driver (using Mailgun through their API), you have to set your Mailgun's secret and domain on `config/services.php`:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => 'your-mailgun-domain',
    'secret' => 'your-mailgun-key',
],
```

And don't forget to install the required `Guzzle` package. Open your terminal and run:

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

If you're using the Mailgun through the API, just make sure this line is set on your `.env` file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
```

And actually you can IGNORE the following directive on your `.env` file. You use this if you're using SMTP protocol:

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME='sandbox8e8c3965d4d14cac9d4f346c3d******'
MAIL_PASSWORD='e662ad1bbef5efd44cb96d32d6******'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Hope this help!